# Есть ли другой вариант реализации данного примера Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, комбинаторика

Есть ли другой вариант реализации данного цикла Python3?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from datetime import datetime

#замеряем скорость
start_time=datetime.now()

n_rows = 100
n_cols = 100
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n_rows, n_cols)), columns=['col%d' % i for i in range(n_cols)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n_rows, n_cols)), columns=['col%d' % i for i in range(n_cols)])  




#1 Есть ли возможности повысить скорость цикла for или можно предложить другую реализацию.
#2 Получившийся результат положить в другой df.(сейчас не удобно, получившийся результат добавляется в тот же df2)
for x1, x2 in itertools.product(df1, df2):
    df2['{0}_{1}'.format(x1,x2)] = df1[x1] + df2[x2] 




# замеряем скорость
end_time = datetime.now()
print('Скорость выполнения скрипта: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))

In [12]:Скорость выполнения скрипта: 0:00:06.134649
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так сильно быстрее уже - через промежуточный словарь. Когда вы добавляете много раз колонки в один и тот же `DataFrame` - это очень медленная операция и тормозит в основном именно она. Кроме того, я беру сразу `values`, это тоже ускоряет сложение.

```
d = dict()
for x1, x2 in product(df1, df2):
    d['{0}_{1}'.format(x1,x2)] = df1[x1].values + df2[x2].values 

df3 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

У меня раз в 20 таким образом при проверке в Google Colab всё ускорилось.

Если надо данные потом всё же в df2 поместить, то можно это легко сделать уже после создания df3.

Comment: Спасибо ! у меня в 7 раз ускорилось

Comment: @VEL Ну, тоже неплохо. Дальше только если запоминать результаты сложения во временный словарь и можно ещё раза в 2 примерно сэкономить, пользуясь тем, что колонка "x_y" в вашем случае равна колонке "y_x" и можно считать её один раз, а не два. Но стоит ли этим заморачиваться - не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

Изначальный код выполнялся:

```
In [12]:Скорость выполнения скрипта: 0:00:06.134649
```

Предложенный код от @CrazyElf

```
d = dict()
for x1, x2 in itertools.product(df_1, df_2):
    d['{0}_{1}'.format(x1,x2)] = df_1[x1] + df_2[x2] 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

In [13]:Скорость выполнения скрипта: 0:00:01.116014
```

Вот еще один вариант:

```
def pir(df_1, df_2):
    pidx = np.indices((df_1.shape[1], df_2.shape[1])).reshape(2, -1)
    cols = ['{0}_{1}'.format(col_1,col_2) for col_1 in df_1.columns for col_2 in df_2.columns] 
    return pd.DataFrame(df_1.values[:, pidx[0]] + df_2.values[:, pidx[1]], columns=cols)
df = pir(df_1, df_2)

In [14]:Скорость выполнения скрипта: 0:00:00.065824
```

Comment: Да, сложить через Numpy прямо матрицы это вообще атас, конечно, по скорости. Интересно было бы до кучи через Numba попробовать ещё ускорить )